# How to save csv to multiple arrays C++

Tags: csv, visual-c++

I am trying to read each line of a file "YearAverages.csp" and assign the first four numbers to separate arrays. Here is a snippet of the file:

```
1969,2.9,1,16.5,19.4,"3,368.20",15.1
1970,4.6,1,17.8,22.4,"3,565.10",20.7
1971,5.8,0.5,17.8,24.1,"3,848.30",26.1
1972,7.3,0.5,16.6,24.4,"3,972.10",32.4
1973,8.1,0.5,16.1,24.7,"4,008.80",35
```

Trouble is I am not sure how to read each line and make this sort of assignment. I was thinking it would be done with a for loop counter. Any guidance would be appreciated as to what direction I can take.

Comment: Perhaps you could start by posting the code that you have already written.

Comment: I'll give you a `hint`. Read each line into a buffer, then you can parse the buffer with a simple pointer (alone or in combination with `strtol` and `strtof`) and easily put any element anywhere you like. (your pointer or the result of `strtof` will both be `NULL` when you hit the end of each line.